# How do I change the primary key in a rethinkdb document?

Tags: primary-key, rethinkdb

Based on [the RethinkDB replace() docs](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/replace/) I am trying to change the primary key of a document. In this case, the primary key is `email`:

```
var renamePerson = function(originalEmail, newEmail, cb){
    rethink.db(DATABASE).table(TABLE).get(originalEmail).replace({email: newEmail}).run(dbConnection, cb)
}
```

This should work, but `unchanged` is `1`, and looking up the new document doesn't seem to return any results.

**How can I change the primary key of a document?**

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research, I found [this quote  from the developers](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1570):

> 'We don't let people change pkeys, they have to delete and reinsert the document instead.'

Based on that:

```
var renamePerson = function(originalEmail, newEmail, cb){
    runningDatabase.getPersonByEmail(originalEmail, function(err, person){
        if ( err ) {
            log('Error finding person to rename', err)
            cb(err)
            return
        }
        person.email = newEmail;
        createPersonRaw(person, function(err, createdPerson){
            if ( err ) {
                log('>>> Err creating new document for renamed person', err)
                cb(err)
                return
            }
            deletePerson(originalEmail, cb)
        })
    })
}
```

(createPersonRaw is just a helper function that inserts a doc, deletePerson marks a person as being deleted)